# Use Apple APIs and Kits on a remote server

Tags: development, developer-program

I'm trying to make a cross-platform desktop app for MacOS and Windows that needs to do music recognition, so I'd like to use ShazamKit by Apple. By the way, ShazamKit is only available on Apple platform.
So in order to allow Windows users to use it I'd like to build a REST API on some remote MacOS servers, send audio to them and get a response from them.
Do you think that this could be possible or I'm violating Apple licensing aggreements?

Answer (score 2):

I am not a lawyer / your lawyer, but this seems cut and dry against section 2.6 of the [developer agreement](https://developer.apple.com/support/downloads/terms/apple-developer-program/Apple-Developer-Program-License-Agreement-20211213-English.pdf) which covers prohibited uses:

> You agree not to install, use or run the Apple SDKs on any non-Apple-branded computers.

The preamble also makes it very clear, the license is not going to cover non-Apple hardware.

> You would like to use the Apple Software (as defined below) to develop one or more Applications (as defined below) for Apple-branded products.

If you were already a developer, you could ask how much a custom license would cost for you to be permitted to do this and build that cost into your financial model, but I would expect a no unless you had a very compelling reason for Apple to host your windows-based API calls.

Your “I’ll run it on Mac server” runs afoul of this clause, also from the very top of section 2.6

> You agree not to rent, lease, lend, upload to or host on any website or server, sell, redistribute, or sublicense the Apple Software, Apple Certificates, or any Services, in whole or in part, or to enable others to do so.

Basically, you’re not really developing for Apple if the data ends up on Windows through a macOS redistribution or hosting arrangement.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. I have already seen those sections of the aggreement, by the way I hoped there was something more elsewhere. For example, ShazamKit can be used on Android devices as Apple already released an official Android SDK, even though the aggreement says that Apple APIs can only be used on Apple devices. So I hoped there was any other licensing aggreement elsewhere with other infos

Comment: Once you are an Apple developer, this is what developer support does, answer your specific questions. They either say yes, here is where it says go ahead, or they’ll send you a link like I did and say ask your contract advisor @giuann post a link to the android SDK please - that would have been excellent to have in the question to show your research.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happened, the developer support linked the agreement and suggested me to ask for a counsel. By the way, as said in the previous comment, there is an android SDK here https://developer.apple.com/shazamkit/ for which I can't find any specific licensing agreement. I asked for it to the support, but I didn't get any helpful reponse about it